# How to get output for bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am getting an error

```
    ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
    Error: Failed to find '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'
      in [
        C:\Users\sfssda\OnlineShoppingCartInA6\DeepCart\src
      ]
 at resolveModule.catch.catch (C:\Users\sfssda\OnlineShoppingCartInA6\DeepCart\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13)
    at <anonymous>
     i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

while developing an application. I installed:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm i bootstrap-scss
```

**app.module.ts** has the imports as

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

**styles.css** has

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: dont import it in the `style.css` add it in you `angular-cli.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Your *angular.json* file should have the bootstrapp scss/css like this

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "options": {
            "styles": [
                ... OTHER SCSS/CSS
                "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
                "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss",
                "src/styles.scss"
            ]
        ...
```